# Автоматический перенос элементов на новую строку при уменьшении ширины страницы

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Всем привет! Появилась задача: смещать элементы при уменьшении окна браузера. То есть, у меня есть блок новостей, всего одна строка, в строке 4 новости, организованный на flex модели. И при уменьшении окна браузера мне нужно, чтобы новости становились в сетку 2x2, если ширины будет не хватать, то в сетку 1x4.

Смотрю на данный момент на механизм flex-box'а.
Придумал решение на `@media screen and (max-width)`, но есть подозрение, что это будет не слишком элегантно и красиво, нежели в случае с flex-box моделью.

То, что у меня сейчас есть на руках, на flex'е:

```css
news {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

new {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  background: teal;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<news>
  <new>Новость 1</new>
  <new>Новость 2</new>
  <new>Новость 3</new>
  <new>Новость 4</new>
</news>
```

Comment: flex-wrap: wrap;  - В одной строке может быть много блоков. Переносятся они или нет определяет свойство flex-wrap.

Comment: @Даниил примерно то, что нужно, спасибо! Но получается сетка 3x2. У меня это выглядит немного странно, потому что в первой строке 3 новости, а во второй одна :)

Comment: можно сделать центровку, чтобы  последний блок отоброжался по центру

Comment: @Даниил да, понимаю, но это всё равно будет выглядеть не очень, согласитесь? Лучше в данном случае сделать сетку 2x2, чтобы всё было красиво и лаконично. Решение-то у меня уже есть, но оно на `@media screen`. Если решения нету, то буду использовать его, что поделать :-D

Comment: @MarkKhromov ну если вдруг кто-то вам сказал что на флексах прям адаптивно-адаптивно будет совсем без медиа-запросов – вас обманули.

Comment: @websnap я не знаю, правда, только начал переезжать на flex. Если такой возможности нету, тогда вопрос можно считать закрытым, помечаю ответ как верный, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не плохая статья по [FLEX](http://css.yoksel.ru/flexbox/)

В одной строке может быть много блоков. Переносятся они или нет определяет свойство **flex-wrap**.

Возможные значения:

**nowrap** — блоки не переносятся (значение по умолчанию);

**wrap** — блоки переносятся;

**wrap-reverse** — блоки переносятся и располагаются в обратном порядке.

Comment: Спасибо за статью, хорошая! Добавил в избранное